# Egit: how to synchronize eclipse project ( local repository) with the remote repository

Tags: java, eclipse, git, version-control, egit

I'm new to Git version controlling. I use EGit plugin with eclipse which again I haven't used before.

My question is, I have created a project (on PC1) in eclipse that is connected with a remote repo which is hosted on Github. I can commit and push them to the remote repo using EGit plugin via eclipse.

If I work on the same remote repo from another computer, say PC2 and i have made some changes to the repo from PC2, how can I sync my code on PC1 with the remote repo and see the changes visually?

if I go to Team -> i can see Synchronize Workspace but that is not what I want and again I don't understand the purpose of it as well (have attached a pic)?
[image]

If I goto Team -> Merge.. below is what I see. It doesn't give me the option to merge with the remote repository and see? 
[image]

Comment: The [eGit documentation](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide/Remote#Pulling_.28merge_or_rebase.29_new_changes_from_upstream) seems to imply that you have to manually do a `git pull` from the Git bash window.  This will solve your problem, although there might also be a way to do using the Eclipse plugin.

Comment: thanks for the comment. But the page says, This page was last modified 10:37, 21 May 2010 . so I guess this is function has been implemented by now

Comment: The option you want is `git pull`.  Check the screen for this option.

Comment: yes it says git pull. but can I do that without using the terminal?

Comment: as said in this page: http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Synchronize_View , " resources in your workspace or a local branch compared to those in another local or remote tracking branch representing the state of a branch from a remote repositor"

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen found the answer. JLYK. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I found the answer. you have to add the following line to the config file under .git

add following to the [remote "origin"] section:

fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*

Thanks to the answer in this post: [EGit: cannot push, cannot pull](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25205845/egit-cannot-push-cannot-pull)