# Git push error, head of distant repo is behind local

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I have a repo on gitlab with my project. I first commit and push this project on windows. After I create a VM on ubuntu and I copy paste my project folder on it. I continue my project on ubuntu and I did commit (without push). I didn'use anymore my windows project. Now when I want to push the project (ubuntu) I have error. I think I have conflict and merging problem.
How can I `push` my project on the repo. I try to `pull`, `fetch` but nothing.

The error is :

```
! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
impossible to push references to 'repo'
tip: The updates were rejected because the head of the current branch is behind its remote peer. Integrate remote changes (eg 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
```

After that when I do a git `pull origin master` I have a lot of conflicts with many files.

Can you help me?

Comment: You shouldn't have copied the working copy, you should have cloned the repo from gitlab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do the `git pull` and resolve conflicting files. Open each one, fix it, then `git add` it. You will find the conflicting lines like that:

[image]

After doing this with all conflicting files, test your code and run `git commit` to merge. You will be able to push after that.

Answer (score 1):

`git` is not allowing you to `push`, `pull`, `fetch` because you copy pasted the entire directory. This has copied the `.git` folder also which git creates on `git init`. Delete the `.git` folder and then reinitialize the git repository with `git init`.

This will create a new `.git` pointing according to the new path.

Answer (score 0):

On *git pull* , **git** will merge the **conflicting files** , You need to solve the conflicts and **commit** again to push (*git push origin master*) updated code on git .

for more info check this link :
[rejected master -> master (non-fast-forward)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11696295/rejected-master-master-non-fast-forward)